# Extract words from a string separated by space in java without split function?

Tags: java, string, function, split

I am trying to split a given string `You don't know who i am` into individual words, "You", "don't", "know"... without split function in java.

I have tried this, but the result is not coming to my expectations.

```
package prog13;

public class split
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s=" abcd efgh!";
        int l=s.length();
        for(int i=0; i<(l-1); i++)
        {
            String word="";
            String finword="";
            char ch= s.charAt(i);
            if(ch!=' ')
            {
                word=word+ch;
                finword=word;
                if(s.charAt(i+1)==' ')
                {
                    word="";
                }
                System.out.println(finword);
                finword="";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result is coming like,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:E:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=60323:E:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-32.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;F:\java class 11 projects\java projects class 11 isc\bin;F:\java class 11 projects\java projects class 11 isc\lib\kotlin-stdlib.jar;F:\java class 11 projects\java projects class 11 isc\lib\kotlin-reflect.jar;F:\java class 11 projects\java projects class 11 isc\lib\kotlin-test.jar;F:\java class 11 projects\java projects class 11 isc\lib\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar" class11.split
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I write this correctly?

Comment: You should declare `String word` and `String finword` outside the for loop. If its inside the for loop it will reset each time.

Comment: now its comming like,a
ab
abc
abcd
e
ef
efg
efgh

Comment: it because you are priting `finword` in each iteration. you should only print it if `ch == ' '`. Then you should get the results you want

Answer (score 1):

The positioning of your print statement and initialization is wrong.
You can try:

```java
        String word="";
        for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch!=' ') // append to current word
            {
                word=word+ch;
            }
            else // if space is found print the previously formed word
            {
                System.out.println(word);
                word="";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(word);
```

Prints:

```
you
don't
know
who
i
am
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public class split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "You don't know who i am";
        String word = "";
        String tempword = "";
        String finword = "";

        int l = s.length();
         for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch != ' ') {
                word = word + ch;
                tempword = word;
            } else if (tempword.length() > 0) {
                finword += '"' + tempword + '"' + " ";
                tempword = "";
                word = "";
            }
        }
        finword += '"' + tempword + '"';
        System.out.println(finword);
    }
}
```

output : "You" "don't" "know" "who" "i" "am"

Comment: This ignore any extra space!